# Access files and folder of other app inside data folder

Tags: android

How to access files and folder of other app inside data folder, I want to get the images of the other app, say from the package **com.example.otherapp** ?

**EDIT**
I want to access files inside Android --> Data --> com.facebook.orca
Any android version, I don't want to create the file explorer, I just want specific files from one app.

Comment: You really need to clarify (not just by tagging): this is on Android? And for which versions?

Comment: @DerGolem I can access it on file explorer apps without root.

Comment: @DerGolem I can see the images in file explorer so it's possible to access that data. It's in Android->Data->package name.

Comment: @DerGolem You deleted your comments?????

Comment: @DerGolem Okay so that is possible to read the files. I tried few codes but not able to access files. So is there any blog or demo which can helpful in writing a code?

Comment: @DerGolem I'm using ES File Explorer and in that app I can access the folders inside android/data/packageName. I don't want SD Card pictures, I want app specific images.

Comment: I don't have the folder `/android/data/`... But I have the folder `/sdcard/Android/data/`... so you have to access the sdcard anyway. Or maybe the internal storage.

Comment: @DerGolem I cannot find any way to access it, I don't know how these apps works,.there are so many file explorer in Google play.